# How to set QListWidget in particular position

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidget

How do i set `QListWidget` in particular position say i have window size of(1000,1000) and i want to set `QListWidget` at position (200,200).

```
    widget = new QWidget();
    setCentralWidget(widget);

    list1->setFixedSize(200,150);
    list1->addItem("Surya TV");
    list1->addItem("Sony TV");
    list1->addItem("Zee TV");

    vertical->addWidget(list1);
    widget->setLayout(vertical);
```

Comment: Do not use layouts if you need fixed positioning.

Comment: ok. then v can set each ListWidget and Button to its predefined position?

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
   void move ( int x, int y )
```

Something like :

```
    p = new QListWidget(this);
    p->move(200,200);
```

In my case "this" is the QMainWindow.
Does it helps?

Comment: no bro. ListWidget is bydefault in its defalut position. Actually i have set CentralWidget too

Comment: Ok then since you have a layout then you cannot use move method.It will not help,the other way i can suggest is using QSpacerItem. Ex: QSpacerItem* pSpacerItem = new QSpacerItem( 200, 200, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum ); oLayout->addItem(pSpacerItem );//oLayout is of type QVBoxLayout

Comment: One more change which you have to make in your code is that you should not use SetFixedSize method .Instead you can use SetGeometry

Comment: @Rupesh Please refer this link:http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html .In this there is a section for "Custom Widgets in Layouts" which very clearly describes how to set the size of widgets in a layout.But all these methods like SetGeometry,SetMinimumSize......will NOT work in a layout.

Comment: @Rupesh here is one more link talking about the similar stuff http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6505

Answer (score 0):

Please use spacers with predefined sizes to pad your list if you are going for layouts. It is better to go for layouts if you have more widgets along with the listWidget in your main form.
If you are unsure, please use Designer to build your forms. This will allow you to have the kind of control you wish achieve in terms of fine grained positioning.
Personally, I do not prefer designer though.